# Angular 11 - Script Added to scripts folder and path to angular.json

Tags: javascript, angular

I have recently added a script file into the src/assets/scripts folder and have placed its path under the scripts section in angular.json.

Question is: Do I need to re-run `ng serve` so that it will be loaded the next time the application runs?

Appreciate the responses.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, If you mention any script in the `angular.json` it will be part of the bundle(meaning its automatically included). If you don't want that to happened, there is a different way to inject the script:

```json
"scripts": [
  {
    "input": "src/external-module/main.js",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "external-module"
  }
]
```

This way the script will be part of the dist, but will not be added to the `index.html`. You'll have to manually load it or add it to the `index.html`

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration

Comment: when I added my script, ng serve is still running, I ended and rerun both ng build and ng serve and the script was now loaded. Adding inject:true may be correct, but I can't for my case but I am accepting this answer still.